# How to pass objects of previous function in R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, environment

I am creating some functions for myself and I don't know how to proceed in order to use an object (e.g. a value) returned from one function to another one, while the console is still running. As an example:

```
first <- function(x){
return(x)
}

second <- function(y){
z <- x + y
return(z)
}
```

So if you call these functions with a '+'...

```
first(x = 5) +
  second(y = 5)
```

I would expect a value of 10. In this particular case, obviously the function second() can't find the object x, because the latter one was assigned in the first() environment.

This style of programming is similar to ggplot(), for example:

```
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y), data = data) +
  geom_point()
```

I know this type of programming implies the use of environments, but I can't get it work. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Looking to ggplot package in github I figured it out, I think:

```
hh_first <- function(data) {

  h <- structure(list(data = data), class = c("hh"))

  h
}

"+.hh" <- function(e1, e2) {

  add_hh(e1, e2)

}

add_hh <- function(h, object) {

  h$data <- paste(h$data, object, sep = "")
  h$data

}

hh_second <- function(data) {

  data

}
```

For example...

```
hh_first('Hi') +
  hh_second(', how are you?')
```

Returns a string 'Hi, how are you?'. The plus operator in this case works with objects of class 'hh'.
Any suggestions regarding the code or perhaps possible errors that this kind of coding may produce are welcome.

Comment: After looking at this again, I may have missed what you are looking for, if so let me know and i will delete or update the answer.

Comment: The ggplot paradigm you reference is fairly complicated; it's actually using it's own special function for adding `ggplot2:::add_ggplot`.

Comment: The ggplot2 package overloads the `+`-operator and the directions for replicating that process involve creating a new class that will be dispatched to the proper code. You should search on generic functions. I think this request is too broad. If you decide to go this route you should be reading either Venables and Ripley's "S Programming" or Hadley's "Advanced R"

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. The solution of Ian Wesley is a good one but does not completely convince me. I will search the generic functions in ggplot package to get an idea, as 42 clear out.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
first <- function(x){
  return(x)
}

second <- function(x ,y){
  z <- x + y
  return(z)
}

second(first(5), 5)
```

OR

```
myX <- first(5)

second(myX, 5)
```

OR

```
library(magrittr) # Which uses pipes, %>%, to pass the results of a function to the first variable of the second function
first(5) %>% second(5)
```

Comment: Using your functions this can also be written: `library(magrittr); first(5)  %>% second(5)`